# Orientation of image from gallery is always 0

Tags: android, image, orientation, exif, android-gallery

I'm trying to load an image from gallery in a ImageView. This code work correctly on Huawei p10, but don't work correctly on Samsung s5 and other devices. When i load the image the orientation is not correctly.
I'm using this function to load from gallery but the orientation is always 0.

```
public void loadPostImage(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE1) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                flag=true;
                path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                int orientation = getOrientation(getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri);
                Log.e("image path", path + "");
                image_post.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

}

private static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return -1;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    return orientation;
}
```

I tried also with EXIF. But nothing is changed.

```
 public void controlRotate(Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
    int exifRotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    switch (exifRotation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
            float photoRotation = 90.0f;
            break;
        }
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
            float photoRotation = 180.0f;
            break;
        }
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
            float photoRotation = 270.0f;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I resolved the problem using this snippet

```
public void orientation(Uri selectedImageUri){
    Uri uri = selectedImageUri; // the URI you've received from the other app
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(in);
        int rotation = 0;
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotation = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotation = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotation = 270;
                break;
        }
        // Now you can extract any Exif tag you want
        // Assuming the image is a JPEG or supported raw format
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle any errors
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());` ??? Please tell the value of `photoUri.getPath()`. I think it's not a valid path. Also tell the value of `photoUri.toString()`.

Comment: When i call controlRotate i use "selectedImageUri" like a prameter that i used in onActivityResult

Comment: Yes i know. I saw that. You do not have to explain that. But why did you tell? You should have answered !y questions. You should have supplied the requested info.

Comment: The value of `photoUri.getPath()` is `/document/image:27716`
The value of `photoUri.toString()` is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A27716`

Comment: So getParh() delivers a meaning less string. The other one is a content scheme. Use that to open n input stream from which the exif interface can read for Android 7+.

Comment: Thanks.
I resolved the problem using input stream.